# Weyl-type inequality for non-Hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis

What is the weakest known condition under which a Weyl-type eigenvalue perturbation inequality holds? Does some analogue hold for normal matrices, for example?

Comment: You may find http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959290047E interesting

or also
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594003548

and also 
http://www.isid.ac.in/~statmath/2007/isid200703.pdf